# Concerning alternating series: test for divergence fails (typo in the book).

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Here is a series:

$$
- \frac 2 5 + \frac4 6 - \frac 6 7 + \frac8 8 - \frac{10} 9 +\dots
$$

The series is convergent (*it says so in the back of the book*) but the test for divergence fails:

We have, if $\lim_{n\to\infty}{a_n} \neq 0$, then the series is divergent. In this case we have 
$$
  a_n=(-1)^{n}\frac{2n}{n+4}.
$$
The $\lim_{n\to\infty}{a_n} \neq 0$, so the series should be divergent. But I know it is convergent.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If a series is convergent the general term goes to zero when $n$ goes to infinity, how can you conclude this?

Comment: @DiegoMath I have a theorem in my book

Comment: The theorem should be quoted in full. If it implies that the series in the OP converges, then the theorem is wrong, a serious problem. If the back of the book says the series converges, that is less serious, merely a typo.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Most probably the typo is the case.

Comment: The relevant theorem is that if $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\ne 0$, and also if the limit does not exist, then the series $\sum a_n$ diverges.

Comment: @AndréNicolas The theorem says, if the series is convergent, then the $\lim_{n->\infty}a_n = 0$.

Comment: @khajvah: That is correct.

Comment: khajvah The two statements are equivalent (your theorem, as in the comment, and @AndréNicolas's . "If p then q" is equivalent to "if not q, then not p".

Comment: @amWhy Yeah, I misread andre's comment, I though he said that limit mustn't exists.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, it does not converge: the term converges to $\pm2$, not to $0$, so at least by the Cauchy convergence criterion the sum does not converge.

Comment: The book says it converges. It might be a mistake but it is unlucky.

Comment: @khajvah: what's the book, and which page? Perhaps, we can figure that out.

Comment: The book is James Stewart's Calculus 7th international edition. It is the problem 3 on page 755.

Comment: It's an error in the book (looking at the page now).

Comment: @NickD.: I now recall the same error in *Stewart* was once before the subject of a question on MSE.

Comment: For reference, the error also appears in the seventh edition of the non-international edition (978-0-538-49787-9).

Answer (score 0):

I think you're taking the wrong sequence. The Leibnitz criteria states that, basically, you transform the alternating sequence into one that does not alternate signs. Then, if the non-alternating sequence converges to zero, the alternating series converges, which it's not your case since the sequence converges to something else or doesn't converge directly.

Comment: Re: "you transform the alternating sequence into one that does not alternate signs. Then, if the non-alternating sequence converges to zero": This part is not necessary. A sequence $a_n$ converges to zero and if only if the sequence $\left|a_n\right|$ converges to zero. (You may be conflating this with a different test, which states that any series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ must necessarily converge if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left|a_n\right|$ does. That test, incidentally, is not specific to strictly alternating series.)